# Source for story of Rashi, the King, and the Four Horsemen

Tags: history, sources-mekorot, rashi, agada-stories-legends

There is a story (you can read the details [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/pol/pol20.htm)) about Rashi telling a King that he will conquer Yerushalaim for 3 days and return with 3 horses and 3 riders. The King returned with 4, but as they entered the city walls, a stone fell down and killed 1 of the riders and his horse, fulfilling Rashi's words.

What is the source of this story?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This story is from [Shalsheles HaKabalah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6618&st=&pgnum=121) (bottom of that page, continues to next page).

Shalsheles HaKabalah is [a history book published by Gedalia ben Yosef Ibn Yechia in 1586.](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%94)

[This article](http://www.gevaryahu.com/Rashi%20and%20the%20First%20CrusadeWP.pdf) (page 16) translates a longer version of the story from a manuscript that they say is from Gedalia ben Yosef Ibn Yechia. The article also discusses the veracity of the story.

Comment: According to this wikipedia article, the author of Sefer HaDorot doubted the veracity of many of the stories in Shalshelet HaKabalah - http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%94

Comment: do we know if this is the earliest written source of this story?

Comment: @Menachem I googled it and found [this](http://www.gevaryahu.com/Rashi%20and%20the%20First%20CrusadeWP.pdf) article. See p. 7 for a discussion of the veracity of the story

Answer (score 1):

I'm familiar with this story and the Crusader Godfrey of Bouillon is definitely the "king" being mentioned. Whether it actually happened is debatable though.

https://www.jewishhistory.org/the-house-of-rashi/