# Did the late Lubavicher Rebbe consider himself a to be a prophet and/or the mashiach?

Tags: messiah, chabad, navi-prophets, chassidic-rebbe, messianism

There are strong suggestions within Chabad literature that the Rebbe was considered to be a prophet (Devar Malchut, see below). Some suggest that the Rebbe himself didn't do enough to discourage his followers to stop thinking that he was moshiach. It could be that he simply didn't know if he was or not. He did however, make attempts to admonish the practice (Sichos Kodesh, Parshas Noach 5752):

> Schneerson responded by writing "It has come to pass that because of his [Wolpo's] activities ... hundreds of Jews have stopped learning Chassidus, and now oppose the Baal Shem Tov and his teachings in actuality. It appeared to some that the Rebbe finally approved of the declaration of the Rebbe as Messiah at a public talk on the 6th of Iyar 1991 when young Rabbi Dovid Nachshon and others repeated Yechi also on the hebrew date of the 15th of Iyar the Rebbe for the first time encouraged the singing of "Yechi", the slogan about the Rebbe being the Messiah."
>   In fact, however, several months later on the 4th Cheshvan 5752, at a farbrengen (Chassidic gathering) on Shabbat Parshat No'ach, the Rebbe publicly admonished those who were singing that song. He threatened to leave the farbrengen, and only stayed so that it would not dissipate.

After having been given some texts (see images below, from Davar Malchut, Mishpatim) of the 'messianic rhetoric' it appears that there are heavy references to the Rebbe (throughout his sichot) that gives the impression that he is not only a prophet but the 'chosen one of Hashem'. Other literary examples include: "the shofet, yoetz and navi of our generation", "we are obliged to listen to him [as a prophet]", "we are not allowed to doubt his prophecy", "they are not only the words of a navi, rather the words of the Lord through this prophet!", "all people in this generation must recognise, that we have merited that Hashem has chosen…", etc.

Although not mentioning it explicitly, the sicha strongly suggests that he is the chosen messiah. (Whether this is considered normative Judaism is not the scope of this question, [related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18785/teachings-of-chabad-lubavitch-controversial-or-not)). These books were written in his lifetime and purportedly endorsed and checked by the Rebbe himself (source needed! I heard this from a Chabad chasid that I was discussing this with).

**Does this mean that he agreed that he was a prophet and the messiah? Or were his followers over zealous in this claim?**

([related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27767/relations-with-messianists) 'relations with messianists')

(related wiki article, [chabad messianism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chabad_messianism))

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: it is important to note that many Talmudic Rabbi's saw their teachers as having messianic qualities, furthermore see this book by Rabbi Gil Student proving the Rebbe is not  Moshiach from the Rebbe's own works: http://moshiachtalk.tripod.com/bikores/

Comment: @Efraim thank you for the reply. 'Messianic qualities' is once removed from 'considering them to be the unrivalled messiah'. Also, concerning the Rabbi's you mention, were they considered to be prophets (I don't know whether this is a pre-requisite)?

Comment: @bondonk http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22814/759

Comment: @bondonk, You'll have to look up the relevant Gemara to be exactly sure and see what the language it uses, I just said messianic qualities b/c I'm not so sure exactly what the Gemara says, I don't have an answer to your question about prophets though

Comment: The way this was explained to me is that there is a "choshesh of moschiach" where someone has the potential to become moshiach if the generation merits it. The precedent usually given is Rabbi Akiva believing this about Bar Kochba. The Rebbe and the Rebbe's followers believed that Rebbe had "choshesh of moshiach" but was not actually moshiach when he was alive. However, now that he has died without becoming moshiach, we assume that this is "choshesh" has expired or passed to a different gadol.

Comment: @Tatpurusha The Lubavicher that I spoke to said that it was 'accepted' that he was (and is), amongst Chabad, the mashiach. The Rebbe downplayed it because he felt it was turning people away from Judaism, but, purportedly, did not deny that he was. Messianists will challenge his death as not being a deciding factor, citing the gemara which mentions that a messiah coming from the dead will be like Rabi (or Rabbi Yehuda?) i.e. it is possible.

Comment: Also, the Rambam (Malchut, chapter 11) suggests that the messiah won't come from someone who was killed (not 'dead', so the interpretation goes), and the Rebbe was never 'killed'.

Comment: @bondonk I think the 'yellows' like to imagine that their doctrine is really held by all of Chabad, but fairly adamant denial that the Rebbe is moshiach has been very common: the explanation I just gave was given to me by a teacher at a Chabad yeshiva. If the Rebbe really believed that he had "choshesh of moshiach" then it would be difficult for him to deny that he was moshiach.

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25794/759

Comment: I'm not sure what would qualify as an answer to this question. Speaking for myself, I long believed that the late Lubavitcher Rebbe had indeed been misinterpreted by over-zealous followers, until one of those followers referred me to the speech you have cited. After reading it I became convinced that the late Lubavitcher Rebbe had indeed been engaged in a deliberate campaign of false messianism.

Comment: This unfortunate matter will in the future (and even now) over-shadow his greatness in Torah and as a leader who did amazing things for the Jewish people. If Moshiach really doesn't come I think 100 years from now people will look back on him as someone who was an amazing talmud chacham that brought many yidden closer to HaShem but was surrounded by craziness and perhaps even perpetuated some of it himself. Time will tell.

Comment: It's important to note that whenever the Rebbe spoke about נשיא דורנו he was referring to his father-in-law and predecessor, the Rebbe Rayatz, and that's made clear at several points in this text itself. Many chassidim took it as an implicit reference to himself as well, because the Rebbe viewed his leadership as continuance of the Rayatz's, but it's hard to say to what extent the Rebbe endorsed that interpretation.

Comment: @shmosel thanks for the point. can you refer to an example please? also, if Rebbe Rayatz was no longer alive why would Rabbi Schneerson refer to him as nasi doreinu? as in, when Rebbe Rayatz was alive he was the nasi doreinu? doesn't seem to flow in the text. perhaps we need context from outside of this text, since its not explicit.

Comment: Like I said, the Rebbe saw himself as a stand-in for the Rebbe Rayatz. See the end of your image, in יב, where it says כ"ק מו"ח אדמו"ר נשיא דורנו, which stands for כבוד קדושת מורי וחמי. And consider the meaning of כפי שהוא בנוגע לנשיא דורנו ונמשך בדור שלאחריו ע"י תלמידיו. The דור שלאחריו was the present one. And when it says לאלתר לגאולה it's referring to the Rayatz's slogan coined during WWII, [לאלתר לתשובה לאלתר לגאולה](https://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%A8_%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%A8_%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%90%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%94).

Comment: @shmosel by that logic someone else could be a stand in for the Rebbe now that he's passed away

Answer (score 4):

According to a number of biographers who have carefully sifted through his writings and researched into private conversations, R. Schneerson never explicitly stated that he was a prophet or the messiah. As Simon Dein has stressed, however, in *Lubavitcher Messianism*, the Lubavitcher Rebbe made many statements during his life, particularly reiterated by followers before the end of it, that were interpreted by a growing branch of Chabad as hinting of his messianic identity:

> Among such statements were these: that his father-in-law, whose soul he was believed to have shared and who was consequently understood as a surrogate or code for the Rebbe himself, was the prince (*nasi*) of this generation and would redeem us; that the prince of the generation was the Messiah of the generation; that this was the generation of the Redemption; that the metaphysical process of separating the sparks of holiness from the domain of evil had been completed; that the Messiah had already been revealed, and all that remained was to greet him; that the messiah was coming right away; that 'the time of your redemption has arrived'; that the final Temple would descend from heaven to a spot in Crown Heights adjoining Lubavitch headquarters, and that only then would the two buildings be transferred to Jerusalem; and finally, that the messiah's name was Menachem. (Dein 55)

Nevertheless, when discussing the messianic fervor others had for him, the Lubavitcher Rebbe seems to have responded disparagingly and/or dismissively of the movement. Chaim Miller, in his biography *Turning Judaism Outward*, cites multiple letters and speeches from the Lubavitcher Rebbe denouncing Chabad adherents who claimed that he was the messiah. This includes, for example, the *farbrengen* incident cited in the question, in addition to his threatening to close the *Kfar Chabad* magazine for wanting to publish an article on the identity of the messiah; additionally, he gave a sermon lambasting *meshichist* "overzealous Chabadniks (*shpitz Chabad*)" for being antithetical to Chabad Chassidut (cf. Miller 404-407).

While the Lubavitcher Rebbe was deeply devoted to learning about and and bringing in the messianic era, the evidence available suggests that he did not agree with Chabad messianics claiming that he was the messiah. It is important to remember that Chabad messianism also escalated after the Lubavitcher Rebbe's paralyzing stroke, when his passivity to "Yechi" chants was seen by some as approval of their beliefs. As to Chabad messianics' claims before his stroke, Yehuda Avner's memoir *The Prime Ministers* offers a potential insight into the Lubavitcher Rebbe's otherwise acquiescent approach:

> Relaxing, he fixed me with those eyes, and with a surprisingly sweet smile, said, "Now tell me, Reb Yehuda, you visit us so often yet you
>   are not a Lubavitcher. Why?"
>
> Still trying to absorb what he had said, I sat back, stunned at the
>   directness of the question. It was true. This, probably, was my fifth
>   or sixth meeting with the Rebbe. Over the years I had become a sort of
>   unofficial liaison between the various prime ministers I served and
>   the Lubavitch court.
>
> Swallowing thickly, I muttered, "Maybe it is because I have met so
>   many people who ascribe to the Rebbe powers which the Rebbe does not
>   ascribe to himself."
>
> Even as I said this I realized I had presumed too much, and I could
>   hear my voice trailing away as I spoke.
>
> The Rebbe's brows knitted, and his deep blue eyes grayed again, into
>   something between solemnity and sadness, and he said, "Yesh k'nireh
>   anashim hazekukim l'kobayim" [There are evidently people who are in
>   need of crutches]. The way he said it conveyed infinite compassion. (Avner 445)

Answer (score 1):

As a Lubavitcher, I just want to clarify some things about the sources you are quoting.
The sicha you have in the picture is the Rebbe's own teachings. **Likkutei Sichos, Sefer Hasichos 5747-5752 ([5750](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/15986), [5751](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/16035), [5752](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/15971)) - are all considered purely the Rebbe's chassidus. The Rebbe approved of every word in those sfarim.** (That is an undisputed fact.)

(There are other sforim that were written up by chassidim based on the Rebbe's farbrengens and sichos (talks), but were not looked over by the Rebbe himself. Some examples would be Sichos Kodesh, Hisvadios)

The sicha you have in the picture is what the Rebbe endorsed to be printed.

If you want to know what the Rebbe's opinion is:
Based on the approved ("muggah" in Chabad terminology) sources, the Rebbe himself pretty clearly states that the Nossi of the generation is the Moshiach of the generation (for example [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=47387&st=%25u05DE%25u05E9%25u05D9%25u05D7%20%25u05E9%25u05D1%25u05D3%25u05D5%25u05E8) - Parshas Mishpatim 5752), 
that our generation is the one that will actually bring the Final Geulah, 
and that the Rebbe is considered a Novi (see the sicha you quoted).

I need to link the sources.

Regarding those instances you mention- that is true. However, based on my understanding - it is clear that the Rebbe says that he is a prophet, and almost explicitly says that he is Moshiach, but what is argued is that it is not our task to go telling the world that the Rebbe is Moshiach. If you know it for yourself, or if someone figures it out themself - fine, but no mitzva to publicize it if that will turn yidden away from Yiddishkeit.

Comment: I'm not sure that "it is an undisputed fact" is evidence to claim veracity

Comment: Also, since he is never explicit about this point exactly it leads many to assume that his mashiach/prophet status was a hope of his chassidim, nothing more

Comment: About Prophet status: Learn the Sicha of Shoftim 5751 - it's quite explicit.

Comment: @bondonk Just an example: Shabbos Mishpatim 5752- the Rebbe said that the current events of that Friday, where the United Nations decided to give money for agriculture instead of for arms, "״וכתתו
 חרבותם לאתים - is a direct cause of Moshiach Tzidkeinu's affects on the world, and the fact that the UN is in New York is significant - it is because the Rebbe, Moshiach, came to NY and began elevating it.
-Take it as you wish, and you don't have to trust me. [Learn it in the source][5].

Comment: Maybe he was Moshiach ben Yosef. Some Rabbis thought they were ben Yosef, or at least their students thought so (e.g. Vilna Gaon).

Comment: "The Rebbe approved of every word in those sfarim. (That is an undisputed fact.)" I think this needs to be backed up with a clear statement by a Chabad leader who does _not_ accept the Rebbe as moshiach. Otherwise you are likely just seeing and quoting people from the circle that agrees with you - a normal thing to do, but one that leads to completely wrong results.

Comment: Since the Rebbe had his first severe stroke in 5752, I'm having trouble imagining that he was able to "approve every word" in the sichos from that year.

Comment: @MichoelR he didn't give sichos after the stroke and I think there's only one little half half of A page that is approved towards vayakheil before the stroke, even though it was a very long sicha. He used to stand for hours and actually give out the sichos, by hand. There's videos of it many people still have them

Comment: @Coreofreality Not following the details here too well, but I repeat my request: This kind of claim needs a quote from a Chabad leader who does not accept the Rebbe as moshiach, or the claim does not seem valid.

Comment: @MichoelR https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likkutei_Sichos He reviewed and extensively edited each of these transcriptions before it went to press, making the Likkutei Sichot the authoritative medium with which to disseminate his teachings.

Comment: "and almost explicitly says that he is Moshiach" this is the problem. "Almost" doesn't count. He was saying that the Rebbe Rayatz will redeem us. People make up their own interpretation that he was really referring to himself when he said that, but if one says that then one can also say that it could refer to someone else now, thus leaving it still unresolved

Answer (score 1):

One of the answers above mentioned Rabbi David Berger; here is his well-known article: https://www.tabletmag.com/sections/news/articles/berger-rebbe-messiah. In it he presents a lot of the evidence discussed above, and also clarifies some of the evidence that was left out by people on various sides. He is a very *un*-sympathetic narrator - as he makes clear.

Answer (score 0):

On 12th Adar 1, 5752 (1992) a representative from the women's group (Mrs. Chava Cohen) gave the Rebbe a tambourine. Plastered all over it was the phrase Yechi etc. As she handed it over she said "This is for the Rebbe, Shlita. With this tambourine the women danced yesterday with joy that breaks through all limitations. With a deep trust in the revelation of the Rebbe, Shlita, King Moshiach, immediately and actually to the complete Redemption." The Rebbe answered with a radiant smile, "This [tambourine] you are most probably leaving with me." The Rebbe handed her a second dollar (this event took place at dollar distribution)and referring to psalm 150, said, "This is for the 'Clanging Cymbals'. This is how it is referred to in Tehillim. It should be in a good time." The headline to the picture which shows this actually happened states "The Rebbe approves our acceptance of him as King Moshiach."

I believe mixed messages have been given out deliberately to confuse those who ask this question. It is documented that the Rebbe stated his father-in-law was Moshiach (and that they shared a soul) therefore he the 7th Rebbe was Moshiach - also he was the prophet of the generation and one is forbidden to ignore a prophet. Is it not a fact that prophecy will only return when we are in Eretz Yisroel?

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Or did you see it?

Comment: @DannySchoemann: There's a video of this happening https://youtu.be/GBBOCZWjp7Q. I don't see this video as answering the question. Although messianics tout this as evidence that the Lubavitcher Rebbe claimed to be the messiah, I think it's another example of equivocation that I discuss in my answer.

Comment: @Aryeh - thanks! I agree about the "mixed messages" in the video, though not sure I agree with "to confuse those who ask this question". Maybe he was simply humoring them. So "equivocation" yes, "evidence" no.

Comment: This by itself doesn't prove anything other that what can be observed that is the Rebbe accepted a tambourine that was gift for him meant to celebrate the coming of mashiach.

Answer (score -3):

Generally, the conflict in chabad is over publicity of the Rebbes Messianic title, not the truth of it(David Berger in fact records the names of many of the movements “anti” leaders who stated they believed the rebbe is moshiach even after gimmel Tammuz). I’ve rarely met a chosid who says the rebbe cannot be moshiach and never said anything of the kind in the first place. Those people, in my opinion, have resorted to twisting the Rebbes clear words in order to escape what they see as a difficult Rambam after Gimmel Tammuz. This, of course, is dishonest. In fact, much of the conversation around this topic is dishonest. People talk about the “clear” record of the Rebbes discouragement of the messianists. People cite different books(like telushkin) citing the same 6 or so negative stories over and over. Aside from the fact that some of these were recorded inaccurately, they make this out as though this was always the Rebbes reaction, ignoring countless letters and videos publicized to the public which show a very positive/permitting reaction. The record is so clear it’s a wonder people attempt to deny it. It seems to me, if ur theory doesn’t account for all the evidence then ur theory is likely wrong, and the evidence suggests negative and positive reactions. 3 such examples which can be found online are 1. that Rabbi Groner, one of the Rebbes secretaries, testified in court that the rebbe approved that the title “melech hamoshiach” can be printed about him in kehos publications. 2. That Yitzchok Springer received permission to print the Rebbes identity as melech hamoshiach in the New York Times 3. The Rebbe agreed to appear on the Super Bowl while Chassidim chanted Yechi to him

Interestingly, there is a video of Sholom Jacobson in 770 where he tells how a person told him that many years ago he was bothered by the talk that the Rebbe was moshiach so he decided to ask the rebbe himself by dollars. He asked “is it true what they say that you are moshiach?” To which the rebbe responded “in 1950 I didn’t want to be rebbe”.

The sichos are clear for anyone not looking to do mental gymnastics.

Comment: For people who aren't chabad, you could make this answer clearer by explaining the chabad terms in this post.

Comment: That "didn't want to be rebbe" bit could mean he didn't want people saying stuff about him